# Condition not being evaluated?

Tags: entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework and I have 8 projects:

```
IQueryable<Project> projects = _context.Projects.AsQueryable();

Boolean? a = null;

projects = projects.Where(x => a == null);

var result = projects.ToList();
```

Shouldn't result also have 8 projects? I get none ...

**UPDATE 1**

On my project code what I am doing is:

```
var result = projects.Where(x => x.IsActive == query.IsActive || query.IsActive == null);
```

So I filter by active only when query.IsActive is not null ...

**UPDATE 2**

I just tried the following:

```
var c = await projects.Where(x => true).Select(x => x.Id).ToListAsync();

var b = await projects.Where(x => condition == null).Select(x => x.Id).ToListAsync();
```

And got the queries:

```
SELECT [x].[Id]
FROM [Projects] AS [x]
WHERE 1 = 1

SELECT [x].[Id]
FROM [Projects] AS [x]
WHERE @__condition_0 = NULL
```

Comment: If you remove the `where` clause, do you get the expected results?

Comment: I assume `projects.Where(p => true)` gives you the expected result?

Comment: Your `where` clause doesn't make sense. You set`a = null` in the prev line and then check for `a == null` in the next line.

Comment: Yes, with true and ToList gives me the expected result

Comment: @Kaf ... Does not make sense because it is a test ... In my project is a little bit different. I was just narrowing the problem ...

Comment: @CodeCaster: I added an update but as you will see the problem is as simples as my first post

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem, but everything works fine. Is `Projects.IsActive` a nullable boolean in the database and the entity property?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this irrespective of the type of `IsActive`. For me it works with both nullable bool and non-null bool columns.

Comment: @Abbondanza: I just added an UPDATE 2 ... I added the SQL generated. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing as this is an Entity Framework Core RC2 bug:
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/5499

Comment: Why close it? Might still be helpful to post a work-around here.